# Is there any way to access a binderised HAL with a normal android app?

Tags: android

I have an Android device and it uses a key from a binderised HAL to decrypt its firmware update file, which I'm trying to decrypt and extract. Is it that only the system apps are allowed to access the HALs? Is there any way to bypass the limit? (if there's any)

I tried to access the HAL in the same way that the system update app of the device does (HwBinder.getService), and it doesn't work. (method throws a NoSuchElementException)

Comment: I suspect you are being denied by selinux, which protects system services from being accessed by unauthorized apps / users. If that's the case, there shouldn't be any way around it (other than being part of the system).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think you are right about selinux since I saw something like "denied DAC_READ_SEARCH" in the logs. Well that's unfortunate.